# My condition control in widget in modal window does not permit to edit exist condition but permit to create and save new

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, magento2

I am create widget in magento 2.3 that extend funcitonality of vendor Catalog List Product. By default Catalog List Product (CLP) does not allow to create and handle several condition control on same page. My widget allow to create several condition control.
Technically each my conditions control open in new modal window. 
When the user need to create condition then he must click on button named "Choose"
Modal window opens and user set the conditions. When the user configures and ready to save condition then he click to button named "Save" on modal window ajax request sending to server and server respond decoded value to parent form input. The user close modal window and click on Save button on parent form. Widget saved. All done. Everything is right until this step:
When user want to edit saved widget and opens modal window saved data converts to aplicable form by another ajax and jQuery Prepend newchild 
< li > 
to < ul >

But prepended data becomes not interactable- user cannot edit and delete loaded rule.
widget.xml

```
   <parameter name="cond1" xsi:type="block" visible="true" required="false">
                <label translate="true">First Conditions</label>
                <block class="MonteShot\MegaWidget\Block\Adminhtml\Conditions\Conditions">
                    <data>
                        <item name="condition" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="id1" xsi:type="string" translate="true">1</item>

                        </item>
                    </data>
                </block>
            </parameter>
```

MonteShot\MegaWidget\Block\Adminhtml\Conditions\Conditions

```
  <?php
namespace MonteShot\MegaWidget\Block\Adminhtml\Conditions;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface;
use Magento\Widget\Block\BlockInterface;

/**
 * Class Conditions
 */
class Conditions extends Generic implements TabInterface, BlockInterface
{



    /**
     * Conditions constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory
     * @param \Magento\Rule\Block\Conditions $conditions
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset $rendererFieldset
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry
     * @param \MonteShot\MegaWidget\Model\RuleFactory $ruleModelFactory
     * @param \Magento\CatalogWidget\Model\RuleFactory $ruleFactory
     * @param \Magento\Widget\Helper\Conditions $conditionsHelper
     * @param \Magento\Cms\Model\PageFactory $pageFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $response
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(

        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Rule\Block\Conditions $conditions,
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset $rendererFieldset,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        \MonteShot\MegaWidget\Model\RuleFactory $ruleModelFactory,
        \Magento\CatalogWidget\Model\RuleFactory $ruleFactory,
        \Magento\Widget\Helper\Conditions $conditionsHelper,
        \Magento\Cms\Model\PageFactory $pageFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $response,

        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->response = $response;
        $this->conditionsHelper = $conditionsHelper;
        $this->ruleFactory = $ruleFactory;
        $this->ruleModelFactory = $ruleModelFactory;
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        $this->coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;

        $this->rendererFieldset = $rendererFieldset;
        $this->conditions = $conditions;
        parent::__construct($context, $coreRegistry, $formFactory, $data);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return __('Conditions');
    }

    /**


    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function prepareElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element)
    {
        $uniqId = $this->mathRandom->getUniqueHash($element->getId());
        $sourceUrl = $this->getUrl(
            'megawidget/conditions_rule_conditioncontent/conditionpagecontroller',
            [
                'name' => $element->getData('name'),
                'uniq_id' => $uniqId,
                'button_num' => $this->getData('condition')[key($this->getData('condition'))]
            ]);

        $chooser = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            \MonteShot\MegaWidget\Block\Adminhtml\Widget\Chooser::class
        )->setElement(
            $element
        )->setConfig(
            $this->getConfig()
        )->setFieldsetId(
            $this->getFieldsetId()
        )->setSourceUrl(
            $sourceUrl
        )->setUniqId(
            $uniqId
        )->setValue($this->getData('condition')[key($this->getData('condition'))]);

        if ($element->getValue()) {
            $page = $this->_pageFactory->create()->load((int)$element->getValue());
            if ($page->getId()) {
                $chooser->setLabel($this->escapeHtml($page->getTitle()));
            }
        }

        $element->setData('after_element_html', $chooser->toHtml());
        return $element;

    }

    /**
     * Prepare form before rendering HTML
     *
     * @return Generic
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {

        $model = $this->ruleFactory->create();
        // $model = $this->ruleModelFactory->create();

        $id = $this->_request->getParam('uniq_id');
        $name = $this->_request->getParam('name');
        $cuttedName = trim(str_replace('parameters', '', $name), '[]');


        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create(
            [
                'data' => [
                    'id' => 'edit_form_modal',
                    'action' => $this->getUrl('megawidget/conditions_rule/savewidget',
                        [
                            'uniq_id' => $this->_request->getParam('uniq_id'),
                            'button_num' => $this->_request->getParam('button_num'),
                            'name' => $this->_request->getParam('name'),
                        ]),
                    'method' => 'post',
                ],
            ]
        );
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('rule_');
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Widget\Block\Adminhtml\Widget\Options");
        $renderer = $this->rendererFieldset->setTemplate(
            'Magento_CatalogRule::promo/fieldset.phtml'
        )->setNewChildUrl(
            $this->getUrl('megawidget/conditions_rule/newConditionHtmlCatalog/form/rule_conditions_fieldset')
        );

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
            'conditions_fieldset',
            [
                'legend' => __(
                    'Apply the rule only if the following conditions are met (leave blank for all products).'
                )
            ]
        )->setRenderer(
            $renderer
        );

        //  $model->getConditions()->setJsFormObject('rule_conditions_fieldset');
        // $model->setData('element_value', substr_replace($_POST['element_value'], '', 0, 26));

        $model->getConditions()->setJsFormObject('rule_conditions_fieldset');
        $fieldset->addField(
           'conditions',
            'text',
            ['name' => 'conditions', 'label' => __('Conditions'), 'title' => __('Conditions')]
        )->setRule(
            $model
        )->setRenderer(
            $this->conditions
        );





        $label = $id . 'label';
        $valueId = $id . 'value';
        $fieldset->addField(
            'button-save',
            'hidden',
            ['name' => 'select',
                'label' => __('Save condition'),
                'title' => __('Save condition'),
                'class' => 'action-close',
                'data-role' => 'closeBtn',
                'data_attribute' => [
                    'mage-init' => ['button' => ['event' => 'saveandcontinue', 'target' => '#edit_form']],
                ],

                'after_element_html' => '

<button data-role="closeBtn" id="rule_button-save-submit-' . $cuttedName . '" type="button">Save</button>
<script>
require([\'jquery\',\'jqueryForm\',\'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal\'], function (jQuery,jqueryForm,modal){

jQuery(document).on(\'click\', "#rule_button-save-submit-' . $cuttedName . '", function () {  

                var serArr=JSON.stringify(jQuery("#edit_form_modal").serializeArray());
                 jQuery.ajax({
               url: "' . $this->getUrl("megawidget/conditions_rule/preparedata") . '", 
               data: { form_key: window.FORM_KEY,serializedArray:serArr},
               type: \'post\',
                success: function (response) {
                              console.log(response.data);
                              jQuery("input[name=\'' . $name . '\']")[0].value=response.data;


                    },
                error: function (response) {
                                              alert(response.message);
                                               console.log(response.message);
                    }

                 }); 









});
});
</script>

']);


        $fieldset->addField(
            'script-area',
            'hidden',
            ['name' => 'select',

                'class' => 'script-area-hidden',
                'data_attribute' => [
                    'mage-init' => ['hidden' => ['event' => 'saveandcontinue', 'target' => '#edit_form_modal']],
                ],

                'after_element_html' => '


<script>
require([\'jquery\',\'jqueryForm\'], 
function ($,jqueryForm){
 jQuery(document).ready(function (jQuery) {  



           jQuery.ajax({
               url: "' . $this->getUrl("megawidget/conditions_rule/newConditionHtmlCatalog/form/rule_conditions_fieldset") . '", 
               data: {JsonToHtml:jQuery("input[name=\'' . $name . '\']")[0].value, form: window.FORM_KEY},
               type: \'post\',
                success: function (response) {
                              console.log(response.data);


                              jQuery(document.querySelector("#conditions__1__children")).prepend(response.data);

                    },
                error: function (response) {
                                              alert(response.message);
                                               console.log(response.message);
                    }

                 }); 

              });
});
</script>

']);



        // $model->getConditions()->setJsFormObject('rule_conditions_fieldset');
        $form->setValues($model->getData());
        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}

//Magento\Widget\Helper\Conditions encode when save button has been pressed
```

And code in modal window

```
  $model = $this->ruleFactory->create();
        // $model = $this->ruleModelFactory->create();

        $id = $this->_request->getParam('uniq_id');
        $name = $this->_request->getParam('name');
        $cuttedName = trim(str_replace('parameters', '', $name), '[]');


        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create(
            [
                'data' => [
                    'id' => 'edit_form_modal',
                    'action' => $this->getUrl('megawidget/conditions_rule/savewidget',
                        [
                            'uniq_id' => $this->_request->getParam('uniq_id'),
                            'button_num' => $this->_request->getParam('button_num'),
                            'name' => $this->_request->getParam('name'),
                        ]),
                    'method' => 'post',
                ],
            ]
        );
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('rule_');
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Widget\Block\Adminhtml\Widget\Options");
        $renderer = $this->rendererFieldset->setTemplate(
            'Magento_CatalogRule::promo/fieldset.phtml'
        )->setNewChildUrl(
            $this->getUrl('megawidget/conditions_rule/newConditionHtmlCatalog/form/rule_conditions_fieldset')
        );

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
            'conditions_fieldset',
            [
                'legend' => __(
                    'Apply the rule only if the following conditions are met (leave blank for all products).'
                )
            ]
        )->setRenderer(
            $renderer
        );

        //  $model->getConditions()->setJsFormObject('rule_conditions_fieldset');
        // $model->setData('element_value', substr_replace($_POST['element_value'], '', 0, 26));

        $model->getConditions()->setJsFormObject('rule_conditions_fieldset');
        $fieldset->addField(
            'conditions',
            'text',
            ['name' => 'conditions', 'label' => __('Conditions'), 'title' => __('Conditions')]
        )->setRule(
            $model
        )->setRenderer(
            $this->conditions
        );


        // $fieldset->addElement($this->getLayout()->createBlock(\MonteShot\MegaWidget\Renderer\Conditions::class));
        $label = $id . 'label';
        $valueId = $id . 'value';
        $fieldset->addField(
            'button-save',
            'hidden',
            ['name' => 'select',
                'label' => __('Save condition'),
                'title' => __('Save condition'),
                'class' => 'action-close',
                'data-role' => 'closeBtn',
                'data_attribute' => [
                    'mage-init' => ['button' => ['event' => 'saveandcontinue', 'target' => '#edit_form']],
                ],

                'after_element_html' => '

<button data-role="closeBtn" id="rule_button-save-submit-' . $cuttedName . '" type="button">Save</button>
<script>
require([\'jquery\',\'jqueryForm\',\'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal\'], function (jQuery,jqueryForm,modal){

jQuery(document).on(\'click\', "#rule_button-save-submit-' . $cuttedName . '", function () {  

                var serArr=JSON.stringify(jQuery("#edit_form_modal").serializeArray());
                 jQuery.ajax({
               url: "' . $this->getUrl("megawidget/conditions_rule/preparedata") . '", 
               data: { form_key: window.FORM_KEY,serializedArray:serArr},
               type: \'post\',
                success: function (response) {
                              console.log(response.data);
                              jQuery("input[name=\'' . $name . '\']")[0].value=response.data;


                    },
                error: function (response) {
                                              alert(response.message);
                                               console.log(response.message);
                    }

                 }); 



});
});
</script>

']);


        $fieldset->addField(
            'script-area',
            'hidden',
            ['name' => 'select',

                'class' => 'script-area-hidden',
                'data_attribute' => [
                    'mage-init' => ['hidden' => ['event' => 'saveandcontinue', 'target' => '#edit_form_modal']],
                ],

                'after_element_html' => '


<script>
require([\'jquery\',\'jqueryForm\'], 
function ($,jqueryForm){
 jQuery(document).ready(function (jQuery) {  

           jQuery.ajax({
               url: "' . $this->getUrl("megawidget/conditions_rule/newConditionHtmlCatalog/form/rule_conditions_fieldset") . '", 
               data: {JsonToHtml:jQuery("input[name=\'' . $name . '\']")[0].value, form: window.FORM_KEY},
               type: \'post\',
                success: function (response) {
                              console.log(response.data);


                              jQuery(document.querySelector("#conditions__1__children")).prepend(response.data);

                    },
                error: function (response) {
                                              alert(response.message);
                                               console.log(response.message);
                    }

                 }); 

              });
});
</script>

']);

        $form->setValues($model->getData());
        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
```

PrepareData Controller

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2019. MonteShot
 */

namespace MonteShot\MegaWidget\Controller\Adminhtml\Conditions\Rule;

use Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data as JsonHelper;

/**
 * Class PrepareData
 */
class PrepareData extends \MonteShot\MegaWidget\Controller\Adminhtml\Conditions\Rule
{

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\Filter\Date $dateFilter
     * @param \MonteShot\MegaWidget\Model\RuleFactory $ruleFactory
     * @param \Magento\Widget\Helper\Conditions $conditionsHelper
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
     * @param JsonHelper $jsonHelper
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\Filter\Date $dateFilter,
        \MonteShot\MegaWidget\Model\RuleFactory $ruleFactory,
        \Magento\Widget\Helper\Conditions $conditionsHelper,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        JsonHelper $jsonHelper
    )
    {
        $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        $this->conditionsHelper = $conditionsHelper;
        parent::__construct($context, $coreRegistry, $fileFactory, $dateFilter, $ruleFactory, $logger);
    }


    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface|\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json|\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface|void
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        if (!$this->getRequest()->getPostValue()) {
            $this->_redirect('megawidget/*/');
        }


        try {
            $serializedConditionArray =
                $this->conditionsHelper->decode($this->getRequest()->getParam('serializedArray'));
            $templateArray = [];
            foreach ($serializedConditionArray as $index => $singleArrItem) {
                if ($singleArrItem['name'] == 'form_key') {
                    unset($serializedConditionArray[$index]);
                    continue;
                }
                if ($singleArrItem['name'] == 'select') {
                    unset($serializedConditionArray[$index]);
                    continue;
                }
                if (!empty($templateArray[str_replace('rule', '', $singleArrItem['name'])])) {
                    $templateArray[str_replace('rule', '', $singleArrItem['name'])] .= ',' . $singleArrItem['value'];

                } else {
                    $templateArray[str_replace('rule', '', $singleArrItem['name'])] = $singleArrItem['value'];
                }
                //$templateArray[str_replace('rule', '', $singleArrItem['name'])] = $singleArrItem['value'];


            }
            $finalArr = [];

            foreach ($templateArray as $index => $data) {
                $indexName = $this->get_string_between(str_replace('[conditions]', '', $index), '[', ']');
                $paramName = $this->get_string_between(str_replace('[conditions][' . $indexName . ']', '', $index), '[', ']');
                $multiValue = str_replace('parameters[conditions][' . $indexName . ']' . '[' . $paramName . ']', '', $index);
                if ($paramName == 'value' && strpos($data, ',')) {
                    $finalArr[$indexName][$paramName] = [$data];
                } else {
                    $finalArr[$indexName][$paramName] = $data;
                }
                if ($paramName == 'value' && $multiValue == '[]') {
                    if ($finalArr[$indexName][$paramName]) {
                        if ($finalArr[$indexName][$paramName]) {
                            $temp = $finalArr[$indexName][$paramName];
                            unset($finalArr[$indexName][$paramName]);
                            $finalArr[$indexName][$paramName][0] = $data;

                        } else {
                            $finalArr[$indexName][$paramName][0] .= ',' . $data;
                        }


                    } else {
                        $finalArr[$indexName][$paramName][0] = [$data];
                    }
                }


            }
            $this->data = $this->conditionsHelper->encode($finalArr);
            $this->message = 'success';

        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
            $id = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('rule_id');
            if (!empty($id)) {
                $this->_redirect('megawidget/*/edit', ['id' => $id]);
            } else {
                $this->_redirect('megawidget/*/new');
            }
            return;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
                __('Something went wrong while saving the rule data. Please review the error log.')
            );
            $this->error = $e->getMessage();
            $this->message = 'success';
            $this->logger->critical($e);
            $data = !empty($data) ? $data : [];
            $this->_session->setPageData($data);
            $this->_redirect('megawidget/*/edit', ['id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('rule_id')]);
            return;
        }
        $resultJson = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();


        $resultData = substr(substr($this->jsonHelper->jsonEncode($this->data), 1), 0, -1);
        return $resultJson->setData([
            'message' => $this->message,
            'data' => $resultData,
            'error' => $this->error
        ]);
    }

    protected function get_string_between($string, $start, $end)
    {
        $string = ' ' . $string;
        $ini = strpos($string, $start);
        if ($ini == 0) return '';
        $ini += strlen($start);
        $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
        return substr($string, $ini, $len);
    }


}
```

Controller that return data that ready to prepend in jQuery

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2019. MonteShot
 */

namespace MonteShot\MegaWidget\Controller\Adminhtml\Conditions\Rule;

use Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data as JsonHelper;

class NewConditionHtmlCatalog extends \MonteShot\MegaWidget\Controller\Adminhtml\Conditions\Rule
{


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\Filter\Date $dateFilter,
        \MonteShot\MegaWidget\Model\RuleFactory $ruleFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Widget\Helper\Conditions $conditions,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        JsonHelper $jsonHelper,
        \Magento\CatalogWidget\Model\RuleFactory $ruleCatalogFactory,
        \Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\CombineFactory $combineModelFactory

    )
    {
        $this->combineModelFactory = $combineModelFactory;
        $this->ruleCatalogFactory = $ruleCatalogFactory;
        $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        $this->conditions = $conditions;
        parent::__construct($context, $coreRegistry, $fileFactory, $dateFilter, $ruleFactory, $logger);
    }


    public function execute()
    {
        if (!empty($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))) {

            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
            $typeArr = explode('|', str_replace('-', '/', $this->getRequest()->getParam('type')));
            $type = $typeArr[0];

            $model = $this->_objectManager->create(
                $type
            )->setId(
                $id
            )->setType(
                $type
            )->setRule(
                $this->ruleFactory->create()
            )->setPrefix(
                'conditions'
            );
            if (!empty($typeArr[1])) {
                $model->setAttribute($typeArr[1]);
            }

            if ($model instanceof \Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\AbstractCondition) {
                $model->setJsFormObject($this->getRequest()->getParam('form'));
                $html = $model->asHtmlRecursive();
            } else {
                $html = '';
            }
            return $this->getResponse()->setBody($html);

        } elseif (!empty($this->getRequest()->getParam('JsonToHtml'))) {
            $conditionDecoded = $this->conditions->decode($this->getRequest()->getParam('JsonToHtml'));
            foreach ($conditionDecoded as $idx => $condition) {
                if ($idx == '1') {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    $id = $idx;
                    $type = $conditionDecoded[$idx]['type'];
                    $rule = $this->ruleCatalogFactory->create();
                    //  $rule->setConditions($conditionDecoded);
                    $combineModel = $this->combineModelFactory->create();
                    $combineModel->loadArray($conditionDecoded);

                    $validateResult = $rule->validateData(new \Magento\Framework\DataObject($rule->getData()));
                    if ($validateResult !== true) {
                        foreach ($validateResult as $errorMessage) {
                            $this->message = $errorMessage;
                        }
                        return;
                    }
                    $rule->loadPost($rule->getData());


                    $model = $this->_objectManager->create(
                        $type
                    )->setId(
                        $id
                    )->setType(
                        $type
                    )->setPrefix(
                        'conditions'
                    )->setData(
                        'conditions', $rule
                    )->setRule(
                        $rule
                    );

                    if (!empty($conditionDecoded[$idx]['attribute'])) {
                        $model->setAttribute($conditionDecoded[$idx]['attribute']);
                    }

                    if (!empty($conditionDecoded[$idx]['value'])) {
                        $model->setValue($conditionDecoded[$idx]['value']);
                    }
                  }

                    if ($model instanceof \Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\AbstractCondition) {
                        // if (empty($this->data)) {
//                            $model->setJsFormObject($this->getRequest()->getParam('form'));
//                            $this->data = '<li class>' . $model->asHtmlRecursive() . '</li>';
//                            $this->data = $model->asHtmlRecursive();
//                        } else {
                        $model->setJsFormObject($this->getRequest()->getParam('form'));
                        $this->data = '<li class>' . $model->asHtmlRecursive() . '</li>';
                        //$this->data = $this->data . "\n" . '<li class>' . $model->asHtmlRecursive() . '</li>';
                        //  }

                    } else {
                        $this->data = '';
                    }
                    $this->getResponse()->setBody($this->data);
                }
            }
        }
//        return $this->getResponse()->setBody($this->data);
        $resultJson = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
        return $resultJson->setData([
            'message' => $this->message,
            'data' => $this->data,
            'error' => $this->error
        ]);
    }
}
```

How i can return interactivity to loaded data

Answer (score 0):

```
  protected function _prepareForm()
    {

        $model = $this->ruleFactory->create();
        // $model = $this->ruleModelFactory->create();

        $id = $this->_request->getParam('uniq_id');
        $name = $this->_request->getParam('name');
        $cuttedName = trim(str_replace('parameters', '', $name), '[]');
//        if ($this->ruleResourceCollection->getSize() == 0) {
//
//        } else {
//            if (!$id) {
//                $model = $this->ruleResourceCollection
//                    ->addFieldToFilter(\MonteShot\MegaWidget\Model\Rule::UNIQ_BUTTON_ID,
//                        $id
//                    )->load();
//            }
//        }

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create(
            [
                'data' => [
                    'id' => 'edit_form_modal',
                    'action' => $this->getUrl('megawidget/conditions_rule/savewidget',
                        [
                            'uniq_id' => $this->_request->getParam('uniq_id'),
                            'button_num' => $this->_request->getParam('button_num'),
                            'name' => $this->_request->getParam('name'),
                        ]),
                    'method' => 'post',
                ],
            ]
        );
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('rule_');
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Widget\Block\Adminhtml\Widget\Options");
        $renderer = $this->rendererFieldset->setTemplate(
            'Magento_CatalogRule::promo/fieldset.phtml'
        )->setNewChildUrl(
            $this->getUrl('megawidget/conditions_rule/newConditionHtmlCatalog/form/rule_conditions_fieldset')
        );

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
            'conditions_fieldset',
            [
                'legend' => __(
                    'Apply the rule only if the following conditions are met (leave blank for all products).'
                )
            ]
        )->setRenderer(
            $renderer
        );


        $model->getConditions()->setJsFormObject('rule_conditions_fieldset');


        try {
            $conditions = $this->conditionsHelper->decode($this->getRequest()->getParam('element_value'));
            $model->loadPost(['conditions' => $conditions]);
        } catch (\InvalidArgumentException $invalidArgumentException) {
            //do nothing
        }

        $element = $fieldset->addField(
            'condition',
            'text',
            ['name' => 'conditions',
                'label' => __('Condition'),
                'title' => __('Condition'),
                'data_attribute' => [
                    'mage-init' => ['button' => ['event' => 'saveandcontinue', 'target' => '#edit_form_modal']],
                ]
            ])
            ->setRule(
                $model
            )->setRenderer(
                $this->conditions
            );
        $sourceUrl = $this->getUrl(
            'megawidget/conditions_rule_conditioncontent/conditionmodalpagecontroller');
        $condition = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            \MonteShot\MegaWidget\Block\Adminhtml\Widget\Options::class
        )->setElement(
            $element
        )->setConfig(
            $this->getConfig()
        )->setFieldsetId(
            $this->getFieldsetId()
        )->setSourceUrl(
            $sourceUrl
        )->setConfig(
            $this->getConfig()
        )->setFieldsetId(
            $this->getFieldsetId()
        )->setUniqId(
            $id
        );


        // $fieldset->addElement($this->getLayout()->createBlock(\MonteShot\MegaWidget\Renderer\Conditions::class));
        $label = $id . 'label';
        $valueId = $id . 'value';
        $fieldset->addField(
            'button-save',
            'hidden',
            ['name' => 'select',
                'label' => __('Save condition'),
                'title' => __('Save condition'),
                'class' => 'action-close',
                'data-role' => 'closeBtn',
                'data_attribute' => [
                    'mage-init' => ['button' => ['event' => 'saveandcontinue', 'target' => '#edit_form']],
                ],

                'after_element_html' => '

<button data-role="closeBtn" id="rule_button-save-submit-' . $cuttedName . '" type="button">Save</button>
<script>
require([\'jquery\',\'jqueryForm\',\'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal\'], function (jQuery,jqueryForm,modal){

jQuery(document).on(\'click\', "#rule_button-save-submit-' . $cuttedName . '", function () {  

                var serArr=JSON.stringify(jQuery("#edit_form_modal").serializeArray());
                 jQuery.ajax({
               url: "' . $this->getUrl("megawidget/conditions_rule/preparedata") . '", 
               data: { form_key: window.FORM_KEY,serializedArray:serArr},
               type: \'post\',
                success: function (response) {
                              console.log(response.data);
                              jQuery("input[name=\'' . $name . '\']")[0].value=response.data;


                    },
                error: function (response) {
                                              alert(response.message);
                                               console.log(response.message);
                    }

                 }); 

});
});
</script>

']);
        $form->setValues($model->getData());
        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
```